# Passive - attribute and Put something down to something

Tags: passive-voice

> What do you put her success down to? - *[from Oxford dictionary]*

> She attributes her success to hard work and a little luck. - *[from Oxford dictionary]*

So in light of these sentences' being grammatical, the following sentences could be also grammatical?

> aa) What is put her success down to?

> bb) What is her success attributed to?

Comment: aa), no way. bb), okay.

Comment: aa**a**) *What is her success put down to?* is the correct passive form.

Comment: @Lambie Thank you.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I got it - What my mistake of aa) sentence composed by me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

aa needs to be

> What is her success put  down to?

but bb is correct